# Regex replace and insert

Tags: java, regex, replace, insert

I'm working on writing a java to insert '*' where multiplication would be done so 5sqrt(25) would be 5*sqrt(25) and so on. To do this I am using regexp to match a number next to a letter "(\d)([a-z]) to problem I am having is that the letters and numbers after the first match are replaced with the ones that where matched for the first one so if my input was "5sqrt(25)+89function(4)" I would get output of 
"5*sqrt(25)+8**5*s**unction(4)" and example of the code I am using is

```
public static void demo(){
    String regex = "(\\d)([a-z])";
    String demo = "5t 8x 9y";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(demo);

    if(mat.find()){
        System.out.println(mat.replaceAll(mat.group(1) + "+" + mat.group(2)));
    }

}
```

this out puts 5+t 5+t 5+t, instead of 5+t 8+x 9+y which is what I want.

how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
System.out.println("5t 8x 9y".replaceAll("(\\d)([a-z])", "$1+$2"));
```

Output:

```
5+t 8+x 9+y
```

Comment: yep, you're right. `$1` refers group 1 and `$2` refers group 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])
```

Instead of using `matches` just do `replace`.Replace with `*`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/23

Comment: what does the look around do? why add them?

Comment: @tarFish try `string.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])", "*")`.So you dont need any capturing

Answer (score 0):

Replace All fits well in this case. You can try:

```
<target_string>.replaceAll("(\\d)([a-z])", "$1*$2")
```